# how to make jinja markup in excel to write in one row in xltpl

Tags: python, excel, jinja2

i want to write data in one row using xltpl but there is little information about it in the documentation
[image]

i try the markup as in the picture but the days are written in one cell

[image]

i couldn't find the answer in the xltpl documentation

Answer (score 0):

For me working when i do like this:
in A1 put {% for day in days %}{{ day }}
in A2 put {% endfor %}
[image: screenshot]